# Get all of the nouns in a book (.txt file) in R and make a frequency table and wordcloud

Tags: r, nlp, text-files, text-mining

I am trying to find all of the nouns in a text file. Originally I converted a .epub to a .pdf file. Then I converted the .pdf to a .txt file successfully and I removed half of the text since I only need to find the nouns from the last half of the book. I want to do this so I can find the frequency of the nouns and then identify them for finals.

I can do the frequency tables normally with the original text files without any transformations and make a wordcloud etc but I cannot seem to filter only the nouns. Any ideas?

```
cname <- file.path(".","Desktop", "egypt", "pdf")
mytxtfiles <- list.files(path = cname, pattern = "txt",  full.names = TRUE) 

#nouns2 and nouns doesnt seem to work :O -Ive tried both ways-
nouns2 <- regmatches(mytxtfiles, gregexpr("^([A-Z][a-z]+)+$", mytxtfiles, perl=TRUE))
nouns <- lapply(mytxtfiles, function(i) {
j <- paste0(scan(i, what = character()), collapse = " ")
regmatches(j, gregexpr("^([A-Z][a-z]+)+$", j, perl=TRUE))})

#transformation if nouns do not work
docs <- tm_map(docs[1], removeWords, stopwords("english"))

#working wordcloud and freq data 
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(docs)
findFreqTerms(dtm, lowfreq=100)
findAssocs(dtm, "data", corlimit=0.6)
freq <- sort(colSums(as.matrix(dtm)), decreasing=TRUE)
wf <- data.frame(word=names(freq), freq=freq)
p <- ggplot(subset(wf, freq >500), aes(word, freq))
p <-p + geom_bar(stat ="identity")
p <- p + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1))             
library(wordcloud)
wordcloud(names(freq),freq,min.freq=100, colors=brewer.pal(6,"Dark2"))
```

I have tried nouns2 and nouns but they return something like:

```
nouns2
[[1]]
character(0)
[[2]]
character(0)
[[3]]
character(0)
```

Comment: Going on a whim with the regex part, replace `^([A-Z][a-z]+)+$` with `\\b[A-Z][a-z]+\\b`

Comment: Why on earth did you prepared TXT file from PDF, when un-zipping the `.epub` would do the better result.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method to find all the nouns, using the `qdap` package.  You can go from here.

```
text <- "To further enhance our practice, the president was honored to have him join the firm, former commissioner and the first to institute patent reexaminations, bringing a wealth of experience and knowledge to the firm and our clients."

library(qdap)
pos.text <- pos(sentence) # tells the count and parts of speech in the text

vec.tagged <- as.vector(pos.text[[2]]) # retains only the tagged terms in a vector
vec.tagged.split <- str_split(vec.tagged$POStagged, "/") # breaks the vector apart at the "/"
all.nouns <- str_extract(vec.tagged.split[[1]], "^NN .+") # identifies the nouns
all.nouns <- str_replace(all.nouns, "NN\\s", "") # removes NN tag
all.nouns

 [1] NA               NA               NA               NA               NA               "novak"          "druce"         
 [8] "was"            NA               NA               NA               NA               NA               NA              
[15] NA               NA               NA               NA               NA               "commissioner"   "and"           
[22] NA               NA               NA               NA               NA               "reexaminations" NA              
[29] NA               NA               "of"             NA               "and"            NA               "to"            
[36] NA               NA               "and"            NA               NA               NA
```

Comment: Am I missing something here? The output seems to be largely non-nouns. It misses most of the nouns, and has some words that do not occur in the text (novak, druce).